# tooltip icon remain inside tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

When I mouse over a tooltip icon (question mark) to show the tooltip, 
how it's possible for the icon to remain inside the tooltip? A sample of desired result is shown below. 
Thanks in advance.

[image: A sample of desired result]

**Update**

Thanks to @Leguest 
Here is the full html, css and jQuery code:
The idea behind this tooltip is not quite original, actually the checkout page of Apple website inspired me!

If you hover over the question mark the tooltip box is displayed, 
Now I want to add click event for tooltip icon so that the tooltip box remains open unless I click on a blank part of the page.

```js
$('a.as-whats-this-toggle').hover(
    function(){
       $(this).next().removeClass('hidden');
    },
    function(){
       $(this).next().addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.as-whats-this-toggle {
    display: block;
    background: #0089d1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 1.4rem;
    width: 1.4rem;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: 100%;
    background: url(../images/icon-help-overlay.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 1.5rem 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    z-index: 1032;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.as-whats-this:hover .as-whats-this-info {
    display: block;
    cursor: default;
}


.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.as-whats-this-info-top {
    bottom: -.5rem;
}

.as-whats-this-info-left {
    right: -.8rem;
}

.as-whats-this-info {
    background: #fff;
    border: .1rem solid #ccc;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 1rem #999;
    color: #666;
    padding: .7rem 1rem 1.2rem 3.1rem;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30rem;
    z-index: 1031;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4974/store.apple.com/shop/rs-transaction/dist/cart.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-left:300px; margin-top:130px">
<info data-title="Information on Estimated Tax" data-uid="tax-help" data-   position="top left">
  <div class="as-whats-this">
    <a href="#tax-help" role="button" class="as-whats-this-toggle" aria-describedby="tax-help">Information on Estimated Tax</a>
      <div class="as-whats-this-info tal hidden as-whats-this-info-top as-whats-this-info-left" aria-hidden="true" role="tooltip" id="tax-help">
        <h3 class="mbs fwb">Estimated Tax</h3>
        <p>The sales tax listed on the checkout page is only an estimate. The final total sales tax will be reflected on your invoice and will include state and local sales taxes, as well as any applicable rebates or fees. In CA and RI sales tax is collected on the unbundled price of the iPhone.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</info>
</div>
```

Comment: Change z-index in CSS of tooltip icon, it should overlay popup

Comment: show us your html, css and js code

Comment: @xar I updated my question by adding the source code